# How to pass parameter for attribute description

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I  want to change or give parameter for  description.

```
[SystemParameterItemAttribute(Code = "C", Description = "descriptionC", OrderBy = 3, UIResourceCd = "EventType_CallEvent")]
public const string ClassToken = "C";
```

for example;

```
public static descriptionC=getDescription();  //decide description

[SystemParameterItemAttribute(Code = "C", Description = descriptionC, OrderBy = 3, UIResourceCd = "EventType_CallEvent")]
public const string ClassToken = "C";
```

My attribute class;

```
public class SystemParameterItemAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public short OrderBy { get; set; } 
    public string Attributes { get; set; }
    public string UIResourceCd { get; set; }

    public KeywordTarget KeywordTarget = KeywordTarget.Default;
}
```

is there any possible way to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything that's a parameter to an attribute must be `const`, so yes, this can be done by declaring `descriptionC` as `const`, like `private const DescriptionC = "descriptionC";` (note: I changed the name of `descriptionC` to follow C# const naming guideline, but feel free to write it however you want). However it is not possible to make a method `const` in C#

Comment: I want to decide DescriptionC 's value on runtime.
like that;
 descriptionC=getDescription();

Comment: That is not possible, attributes are a constant concept, they add metadata to a type, conceptually they're not meant to be modified at runtime. This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to change description area because of  multi language support.
I need to assign appropriate value which stored in the dictionary.

Comment: Then you should think about a different approach. Perhaps storing a key to the dictionary in the attribute, then you can change the dictionary at runtime.

Comment: You shouldn't be showing an end-user the string in your attribute directly, that's not what attributes are really for. Also, if you do, the description of every single instance of `ClassToken` will be the same, because attributes are a *type* level thing (like `static)`. Instead, the view layer should decide when and how to translate any given value. In this case you could use multi-language resource files and use the description as the key to query the resource files